# In .NET, why are constants evaluated at compile time rather than at JIT time?

Tags: c#, .net, constants

I got a bit of a surprise today when I changed the value of a publicly-visible constant in a static class and then replaced an old copy of the assembly with the newly-compiled version.  The surprise was that the existing program that referenced the assembly didn't pick up the new value of the constant.  That is, I didn't re-compile the executable but rather just replaced that one assembly.

A full description of my experiment is at [How constant is a constant?](http://blog.mischel.com/2010/12/10/how-constant-is-a-constant/)

I'll admit to being very surprised by this behavior.  I understand what's going on, but I don't understand *why*.  Is there a particular technical reason why constants couldn't be picked up at JIT time rather than compile time?  Are there cases where doing that would break things?

Comment: This is a behavior discussed in too many books, blog posts, so it is not that surprising in fact :)

Comment: @Lex: Oddly, I'd never run across a discussion of it before. I still wonder *why*, though.

Comment: I still don't get what the advantage of baking it into the using assembly is.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Constants are supposed to be *constant*. For *all time*. Constants are things like the value of pi, or the number of protons in a lead atom.

If your constant changes, **it wasn't really a constant**; use a readonly field instead.

Also see the Framework Design Guidelines, which state:

> Use constant fields for constants that will never change. The compiler burns the values of const fields directly into calling code. Therefore const values can never be changed without the risk of breaking compatibility.

Essentially, changing a constant without recompiling everything that depends on it is every bit as broken as changing the signature of a method without recompiling everything that depends on it. The compiler "bakes in" all kinds of assumptions about information about metadata from referenced assemblies when it compiles a dependent assembly. If you make *any* change, you cannot expect things to simply keep on working.

Comment: Does the JIT compiler evaluate the readonly fields and then treat them as constants when compiling to native code?  That is, is there a performance difference between using a constant and using a readonly field?

Comment: @Jim: I don't know. First off, there are a good half dozen or more JIT compilers and I am an expert on none of them. Second, JIT compilers often change their behaviour based on stuff that happens at runtime, like whether a debugger is attached or not. Third, if you are concerned about performance, write the code both ways, run it, and see if you can measure a difference. If the difference is too small to measure then it's probably not a difference you should be worrying about in the first place.

Comment: I heard PI is now exactly 3.

Comment: @Eric: Fair enough.  I wasn't particularly worried about the performance.  More, just curious.  This does change my view of what a constant is, though.  Thanks.

Comment: @ChaosPandion: In a world where hexagons are circles, sure.

Comment: @Eric, I just became recently aware of your work, the more of your stuff that I run into lately, the more awesome I'm finding your stackoverflow posts, keep up the awesome :-P.

Comment: @ChaosPandion - I've been told it's healthier to always have the smaller PI, and I have to admit, I have a problem with my too-large circumference - but I'm sticking with the original, no matter how irrational

Comment: @Eric Lippert: Your last sentence says, "If you make *any* change, you cannot expect things to simply keep on working."  Just to clarify:  you mean any change to metadata, right?  As in changing public interfaces?  I assume that the size of a publicly-visible structure would fall into that category as well.  But if I change an implementation detail, like the value of a `readonly` field?

Comment: @Jim: I meant "to metadata" but I suppose the larger point applies too. If you change behaviour, you can break someone. Heck, we break people by fixing bugs distressingly often; sometimes people come to rely on those bugs.

Answer (score 1):

There is also a third way to declare "constants": a public static property.

```
public static string ConstString {get{return "First test";}}
```

This has the versioning semantics of a readonly field, but if the jitter inlines the getter it becomes a jit-time constant. And unlike `const` it can be used on user defined types.

I think it's a good idea to use static properties for value-types and string, but not for user defined classes, since you don't want to allocate a new instance on each property access.

I used this in my FixedPoint type like this:

```
public struct FixedPoint
{
  private int raw;
  private const fracDigits=16;

  private FixedPoint(int raw)
  {
    this.raw=raw;
  }

  public static FixedPoint Zero{get{return new FixedPoint();}}
  public static FixedPoint One{get{return new FixedPoint(1<<fracDigits);}}
  public static FixedPoint MaxValue{get{return new FixedPoint(int.MaxValue);}}
}
```