# String constants embedded twice in .Net?

Tags: c#, .net

Say I have a simple (the simplest?) C# program:

```
class Program {
    static void Main() {
      System.Console.WriteLine("Hello, world");
    }
}
```

If, I compile that code and look at the resultant .exe, I see the "Hello, world" string  in the exe image as expected.

If I refactor the code to:

```
class Program {
    const string Greeting = "Hello, world";
    static void Main() {
      System.Console.WriteLine(Greeting);
    }
}
```

If I compile that code and look at the resultant .exe, I see the "Hello, world" string literal in the exe image twice. This was surprising to me. I was under the impression that string literals were shared, and that it would therefor only show up in the image one time. Can anyone explain this? Perhaps this second copy of the string is needed for reflection metadata?

Comment: As far as I know, the intern operation happens during JIT, not the compile to IL. You'll get the same literal in the assembly over and over. But at run-time, those all get compiled to a reference to the same interned literal. You see two instances in your second case, because the literal exists twice (once for the `const` declaration and then again where it's actually used).

Comment: In your 2nd case, the string is a constant and will never change. The compiler may have decided that it is more faster to include the string where it is used instead of taking more than one step to get the desired value.

Comment: Where is Eric Lippert when you need him?

Comment: My guess is that it is stored in a metadata table and a constant table. Constants can only be a of few very narrow types and I would guess the table doesn't allow arbitrary references to other metadata tokens. Constants get compiled into any assembly that uses them and are not dynamically looked up at runtime.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan Release|Any CPU (prefer 32bit). I've tried other platform settings too, all with the same result.

Comment: I suppose what really counts is what happens post-JIT

Comment: This is a related link...http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4414228/in-net-why-are-constants-evaluated-at-compile-time-rather-than-at-jit-time

Comment: @EmmadKareem "The compiler may have decided that it is more faster" -- That's got nothing to do with it. *Not* replacing the constant by its value during compilation would be incorrect according to the CIL specification, *that* is why it does get replaced. (In this particular case, the C# specification might allow either, but in general, the C# specification requires the current behaviour too.)

Comment: This is entirely normal.  One copy is the interned string, it will be used at runtime and probably the one you expected to find back.  The other is stored in one of the metadata tables, the one that stores *const* values.  Not just strings, any const.  It will only be used when you use Reflection or if you make it public.  Ecma-335 is an excellent and very readable resource for these kind of minute implementation details.

Comment: @The Muffin Man, Lippert not needed for something that simple

Comment: @HansPassant I believe that's an incorrect understanding. `const` causes the IL to actually inline the literal. (The *compiler* actually fills in the value instead of referencing it from somewhere else.) So wouldn't all the copies be used at runtime when the instruction is executed?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The [ECMA-335 CLI specification](http://www.ecma-international.org/publications/standards/Ecma-335.htm) sheds some light on this. A C# `const` is declared as a `static literal` field in IL. From section I.8.6.1.2 (emphasis mine):

> The *literal* constraint promises that the value of the location is actually a fixed value
>   of a built-in type. The value is specified as part of the constraint. **Compilers are
>   required to replace all references to the location with its value**, and the VES therefore
>   need not allocate space for the location. This constraint, while logically applicable to
>   any location, shall only be placed on static fields of compound types. **Fields that are
>   so marked are not permitted to be referenced from CIL (they shall be in-lined to their
>   constant value at compile time), but are available using reflection and tools that
>   directly deal with the metadata.**

Thus the compiler takes the constant value and replaces it throughout the code. It is not allowed to reference the constant storage. What it does from there, is what it does for any other literal string. It gives it a slot in the metadata table and uses the `ldstr` op code to load the string. Thus, the value appears twice in your assembly. Once in the storage location for the constant, which cannot be referenced by a compliant compiler. And another time in your metadata table.

Comment: Assuming this passage is from the CLS, not the C# specification, I believe that the "compiler" mentioned in this passage is the JIT compiler, not the C# compiler. But the original question is asking why the C# compiler emits the IL that it does.

Comment: @PeterDuniho I read it the opposite way, with this passage referring to and thus explaining why the C# compiler emits the IL it does. The C# compiler doesn't do the inlining, the JIT compiler does. It's the CLR that adds it to the intern pool at runtime not the C# compiler at compile time.

Comment: @PeterDuniho It is from the ECMA-335 CLI specification (updated to reflect that). "Compilers" refers to language compilers that are producing CIL assemblies throughout the document. In a few, places it refers to "CIL-to-native-code" compilers, which is what the JIT compiler is. The C# compiler does what it does, in part, because it is required by the quoted section in the CLI specification.

Comment: @rism: ah, yes. You're right...it's imposing the requirement on the generators of IL, not the consumers. So not only is the C# compiler allowed to repeat the string literal, the CLS actually requires it. Either way, the bottom line is the same: the actual interning happens at JIT, not in the C# compiler. Indeed, the C# spec doesn't even mention the word "intern".

Comment: One very practical side effect is that if your code references a `public const` from a library, then your code must be *recompiled* to update the `const` value. The [MSDN documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e6w8fe1b.aspx) even says so: "... [O]ther code compiled with your libraries will have to be recompiled to see the changes." (That's why I never use `public const`; I use a `static readonly` if it needs to be `public`.)