# Is it possible to use reflection to access constants used in a method?

Tags: c#

With the following code, is it possible to use Reflection in `MethodA()` to find out which constants have been used in the `MethodB()`?

```
public class Foobar
{
    protected const int TEST1 = 12;
    protected const int TEST2 = 5678;
    protected const int TEST3 = 83;

    public void MethodA()
    {
        MethodInfo mi = typeof(Foobar).GetMethod("MethodB");
        MethodBody mb = mi.GetMethodBody();
        // At run time, how can I determine which constants where used in MethodB()?
    }

    public void MethodB()
    {
        int TestToRun = TEST2;
    }
}
```

Comment: Not really, the CLI spec requires that constants fields (marked with the literal modifier in CIL) are not referenced where they are used, but instead encode the data from constant into the call site. There is no difference between using the constant `TEST2` and using a literal value of 5678 in the source code. See [my answer to this related question](http://stackoverflow.com/a/27326156/517852).

Comment: To add what commenter mike z said, you _can_ determine the constant _value_ that was used, by retrieving the IL and inspecting it. But a) doing so is a royal pain, and b) it will tell you only the value, not the name of the defined constant (or even _whether_ a defined constant was used instead of a literal). All that said, your question smells a bit of an [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). You might consider taking a step back to think about what you _really_ want/need to do here, and propose an answerable question about _that_.